# How can I get a phone number customers can sms to that posts the information to my website?

Tags: php, sms

i need an sms service that can gives me a phone number and then my customers can send me sms to that number. then posts the sms information to my website like http://xx.com/newsms.php?body=hey

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Twilio](http://twilio.com) recently released a [SMS API](http://www.twilio.com/sms/). With Twilio you can:

- Get a unique phone number (not a keyword at a shared short code).
- Easily connect it via a HTTP POST

It's ridiculously simple. Check out [the API](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/2008-08-01/twiml/sms/twilio_request).

Comment: +1. I just started playing around with Twilio and it is super easy.

Comment: @Nick Yeah, it's hard to quantify 'hard' and 'easy' when it comes to APIs, but Twilio is certainly easy. I find the REST based call control and the XML based call 'script' fit nicely into a MVC framework.

Answer (score 2):

Try www.textmarks.com - they got a PHP API as well.

Comment: Wanted to note that the textmarks phone number is not unique, you register a 'keyword' and text it (along with the rest of the message) to 41411.

Answer (score 1):

If the content can be public or semi-public you might consider using Twitter, which allows various ways of posting via SMS. Their API lets you do pretty much whatever you want with the resulting feed.

An upside of this could mean extra exposure for your site, depending on how you implement it. This is especially true if any of your customers happen to be heavy Twitter users. Also, people would be not be limited to SMS, but could post via web or twitter apps.